# Page title in browser is different than in WordPress settings

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My website Url is [www.hejbarn.de](http://www.hejbarn.de) and I renamed the title of the website to **hej barn - Hochwertige Krabbelschuhe**, but the maintenance site (the only one which is online by now) has still an old name.

Why that?

Comment: Did you clear WP Fastest Cache's cache after changing the name of the site?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming and should be closed, since it is off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I cleared the cache but nothing happened. Justin, why is it off topic? Could you explain that to me? Should be something which is programmable.